# Deploying ROO application on jboss (7)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-roo, jboss7.x

I created a Spring Roo Application based on this tutorial: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html

After using the command line interface to create my entities I deployed it to my JBoss (7.1.0.Final)

I called the web interface and everything was working fine at first view. But when I tried to get my Stored "Labels" I got the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Labels is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Labels o]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Labels is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Labels o]
```

The class Lables is generated via the cli and is annotated correctly.

When I deploy the exact same application on a Tomcat 6, everything works fine... Get data from the database, write data to the database, ...

Does anyone of you know what I have to do to get the application running on a jboss?

If you need any further information please let me know and I'll provide it.

Thx in advance!

BR,

TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. If you run in the same problem just have a look [here](http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/12/25/deploying-spring-roo-mysql-applications-on-jboss-as7/)